# convert datetime to string symfony 3.3

Tags: php, symfony-3.3

Hi i have a field in my entity return an object (dateTime)

```
object(DateTime)[13335]
public 'date' => string '1970-04-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
public 'timezone_type' => int 3
public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

I would like to get Day,month,year as a string .

How can I do this using php symfony in my controller.

Answer (score 6):

DateTime class ia a representation of date and time which creates an object of DateTime. With the help of that we can convert date from one format to another. Also can add, subtract day, hours, minutes...

Here `$obj` is an object/instance of `DateTime`. `$obj` might be your object.

```
$obj = new DateTime('1970-04-01 00:00:00.000000');
```

Using that `$obj` we can convert the date as day-month-year format.

```
$dmy = $obj->format('d-m-Y');

// echo $obj->format('d'); // Get only day
// echo $obj->format('m'); // Get only month
// echo $obj->format('Y'); // Get only tear

echo $dmy; // converted new date
```

You can use such code in your controller. For more specification about [**DateTime**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/O1HnP)